# Function candidates and declaration order

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following snippet:

```
template<typename T>
int foo(T) {
  return 1;
}

struct my_struct{};

template<typename T>
int do_foo(T t) {
  return 
      foo(my_struct{}) + // 1   
      foo(t);            // 2 (via ADL)
}

int foo(my_struct) {
  return 2;
}

int main () {
  return do_foo(my_struct{});
}
```

At first glance, the "non-dependent" call to `foo` will return `1`, and the "dependent" one will return `2`.

However, in the Standard we find [the following paragraph](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#temp.dep.candidate):

> If the call would <...> find a better match had the lookup within the
> associated namespaces considered **all the function declarations** with
> external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation
> units, not just considering those declarations found in the template
> definition and template instantiation contexts, then the program has
> **undefined behavior**.

It is unclear whether this paragraph speaks about dependent names lookup only - so I am wondering if it applies to the above code, thus making it ill-formed.

Could you please construct an example that would illustrate this paragraph's meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This entire paragraph only applies to functions resolved with ADL:

> For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name [...]
> If the call would [...]

(Here "the call" refers to each call with a dependent name, so this wouldn't apply to `foo(my_struct{})`, which isn't dependent)

The second case is covered by the [one definition rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr):

> There can be more than one definition of a [...] non-static function template [...] in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and the provided definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - [...]
> - in each definition of D, corresponding names, looked up according to [basic.lookup], shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of D, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution and after matching of partial template specialization ([temp.over]), [...]

Your code should be well defined, as long as in no other translation units the definition for `int foo(my_struct)` comes before the definition for `template<typename T> int do_foo(T t)`.

---

As for an example for [temp.dep.candidate], the following two translation units would have undefined behaviour:

```cpp
template<typename T>
int foo(T) {
  return 1;
}

struct my_struct {};

template<typename T>
int do_foo(T t) {
  return foo(t);
}

int main() {
  return do_foo(my_struct{});
}
```

```cpp
struct my_struct {};

int foo(my_struct) {
  return 2;
}
```

(Since `int foo(my_struct)` would be a better match but is not found in the template instantiation context)

Comment: Thanks!  As for the example, I'm trying to construct something that does not involve ODR-violation, but is solely based on the order of definitions and the "duality" of the instantiation point (both the call-site and the end of the translation unit). I once encountered such an example, but can't recall what it looked like :).